# Is it possible to make certain data available to certain users on a public mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database

Let's say we have a public DNA database running on mysql. Database contains only complete data. In this scenario, some special users want to add experimental data to the database, which may not be complete or they don't want it to be visible to everyone. Instead they want the experimental data to only be visible to users with correct privileges. What approach would you take to achieve this?

Comment: The database is hosted on our servers and accessed using our java web start tool. Does that answer you question?

Comment: I want to keep that as my last option. I'm wondering, if I can achieve that without creating second database.

Comment: I don't think that would work because the experimental data needs to be added to the existing tables. DB structure needs to stay the same.

Comment: I could go with creating views, would that be my only option in this case apart from creating a second database?

Comment: Yes I would believe so..

Answer (score 1):

Presumably these datasets are large, and performance is important. That means the privilege system should be as coarse as possible.

If I were doing this, I'd create a "public" database, and use the MySQL GRANT command to allow guest users to SELECT on that database.

For example:

```
CREATE USER 'guest'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'changethispassword';
GRANT SELECT ON public.* TO 'guest'@'%';
```

Then, for the nonpublic datasets, I'd put them into other databases, and be more selective about the users GRANTed privileges.  For example, these GRANTs give two different users access to private information and the public information.

```
CREATE USER 'venter'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'changethispassword';
GRANT SELECT ON public.* TO 'venter'@'%';
GRANT SELECT ON celera.* TO 'venter'@'%';
CREATE USER 'collins'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'changethispassword';
GRANT SELECT ON public.* TO 'collins'@'%';
GRANT SELECT ON hgp.* TO 'collins'@'%';
```

A user who has SELECT privileges on, let us say, the `public` database and the `celera` database, can issue queries like this allowing seamless (if not optimally performing) merging of private and public data.

```
 SELECT whatever 
   FROM public.AGCT
  UNION ALL
 SELECT whatever
   FROM celera.AGCT
```

Of course, it has to make scientific sense to take the union of these datasets. That may or may not be the case.

Don't be alarmed at the idea of creating multiple databases. They really are nothing more complex than directories in a computer file system. A single server can deliver dozens of them without any problems.

MySQL is definitely up to this kinds of security. Hosting providers run multi-tenant servers routinely.

Comment: Please look at comments under OP's original post before answering. "I want to keep that as my last option. I'm wondering, if I can achieve that without creating second database. –  Brkk yesterday"

Answer (score 0):

I would consider MariaDB (a MySQL-compatible database written by MySQL's founder) over MySQL, as it supports [roles](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/roles-overview/).

Neither of them support Row Security like Oracle does, but you can mimic it by adding an "owner" column with the name of the role that can select/update the row.

Add a WITH CHECK OPTION view that checks that the current_user is in the role specified in that column.

Add a trigger to set owner value properly.

update: If you can't alter the table but can add new ones, add a new one w same key as original, and add owner column, and join the tables in your view.

See

http://www.sqlmaestro.com/resources/all/row_level_security_mysql/

Comment: While this would be a viable option in other environments, the OP cannot change DB/table structures.

Comment: @BK435 The OP didn't mention any such constraint.

Comment: @EJP please look at comments under OP original post.   "I don't think that would work because the experimental data needs to be added to the existing tables. DB structure needs to stay the same. –  Brkk yesterday"